# Scheduling Windows Mobile apps to run

Tags: windows-mobile, scheduled-tasks

How do you schedule a Windows Mobile application to periodically start up to perform some background processing.  For example, assume I'm writing an email client and want to check for email every hour, regardless of whether my app is running at the time.

The app is a native C/C++ app on Windows Mobile 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function you need is:

`CeRunAppAtTime( appname, time )`

that isn't the exact signature, there is also `CeRunAppAtEvent`, they should both be in the MSDN docs (but linking is useless the way MSDN urls always change)

The normal way to use these (and `RunAppAtTime` in the managed world via `OpenNETCF.Win32.Notify` ) is that for periodic execution, every time your app runs, it will rescedule itself for its next run-time.

If your app is running, the new instance should bring up the already running process. If it isn't running, then it is just like starting up normally - from mmory it passes some argument to the process so it can tell it is being scheduled and not started some other way.

Comment: CeRunAppAtTime is obsolete - have a look into the header notify.h where it is defined. Better to use CeSetUserNotificationEx instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use CeSetUserNotificationEx instead of CeRunAppAtTime (as this is deprecated).