# Schedule app in BREW

Tags: scheduled-tasks, brew-framework, brewmp

Is there any way to launch get a BREW application started according to a schedule? This is basically the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446/scheduling-windows-mobile-apps-to-run), only for BREW instead of Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is.
See documentation on the ISHELL_SetAlert() 
It up to you to check if Alerts that been assigned survive reboot of the device. 
There is a trick that you can run some code when receiving alert without becoming foreground  application by not calling IShell_Activate But it requires a special care.