# Is there a way to schedule a task in Windows Mobile?

Tags: .net, api, windows-mobile, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple question: is there a way in Windows Mobile to schedule a specific task, for example running a .NET program or send a mail, to a precise date and time? Whatever the technology is, I mean native API, .NET classes or even an existing Windows Mobile program.

I am about to start a project but before I want to be really sure that I am not reinventing the wheel (I hate that!).

Thanks.

Comment: Related, but with focus on native WinMo apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446/scheduling-windows-mobile-apps-to-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like that I would consider http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html. Not sure, if it ports to Windows Mobile, but it is open source. ;)

There is always the option of putting tasks in a time-sorted list for a background thread to operate on. If you need persistance, then a database or xml file.

Comment: Great project! I will take a look to know if it can run on the compact CLR.
For persistence, as I am running WM and that this is concerning a small amount of data, XML would be less consuming.